# JQuery Timepicker behind ModalPopupExtender

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, modalpopupextender

I want to fix the `z-index` of the JQuery Timepicker behind **2 layer** of `modalPopupExtender`. So far I try to fix it by changing the z-index of `.ui-timepicker-div` to `100002` like in here:

```
.ui-timepicker-div
{
    z-index:100002;
}
```

but still no luck. Any suggestions of what possible approach to fix this? It can be either in jQuery localization or pure css coding.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eurika! I finally manage to fixed this with combined tweaks from the following scenario:

1. The 2-Layer modalPopupExtender are posting back. That means that the
   jQuery localize earlier are gone. To fix this issue, instead of
   `$(document).ready(function() {});`, you have to use `function
   pageLoad(){}` like this:

   ```
   function pageLoad()
   {
      $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtTimeSlotFrom').timepicker({
           hourGrid: 4,
           minuteGrid: 10
      });
   }
   ```
2. Now, to fix the `z-index`, I include `beforeShow` config in localization like in here:

   ```
           $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtTimeSlotFrom').timepicker({
               hourGrid: 4,
               minuteGrid: 10,
               beforeShow: function() {
                   setTimeout(function(){
                       $('.ui-timepicker').css('z-index', 16777271);
                   }, 0);
               }
           });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
.ui-timepicker  //on .ui-datepicker because it gives z-index to this div at runtime and add position:absolute;
{
    z-index:100002 !important;
    position:absolute;
}
```